# Custom grouping of numerical values pivot using vba codes

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of prices for the products sold and the price changes from last week, now I am calculating percentage change and I am writing vba codes to create a pivot table including the grouping of the percentage ranges.

With the help from fellow member, I can ranges of 10.0% however, I need to revise the codes to that percentages below 0.0% is one group (<0.0%), more than 100.0% (>100.0%)is one group, and between them, I need to have ranges 0.0% - 9.9% and 10.0% to 19.9% and so forth.

I changed the codes slightly to suit my needs (replace "to" with " -") but I only added .0% so now ranges are showing as 10.0% instead of 10% but I still need help on change the way I group them.

```
 Option Explicit

Sub GroupPercents()
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField

Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("% Premium Difference") '<= Change as appropriate
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("% Premium Difference from Prior Term2") '<= Change as appropriate
PercentGroupings pf, -1, 1, 0.1
End Sub

Sub PercentGroupings(pf As PivotField, lFrom As Double, lTo As Double, lGroup As Double, Optional sDelim As String = " - ")

Dim pi          As PivotItem
Dim sCaption    As String
Dim vSplit      As Variant
Dim vItem       As Variant
Dim i           As Long


With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With


On Error Resume Next
pf.LabelRange.Ungroup
On Error GoTo 0
pf.LabelRange.Group Start:=lFrom, End:=lTo, By:=lGroup
pf.Parent.ManualUpdate = True


'Format so that groupings appear as % values
For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
    With pi
        If InStr(.Caption, "<") > 0 Then
            'Less Than Group
            .Caption = "<" & Split(.Caption, "<")(1) * 100 & ".0%"
        ElseIf InStr(.Caption, ">") > 0 Then
            'Greater Than Group
            .Caption = ">" & Split(.Caption, ">")(1) * 100 & ".0%"
        Else
            sCaption = ""
            vSplit = Split(pi.Caption, "--")
            If UBound(vSplit) = 1 Then
                'Negative numbers
                .Caption = vSplit(0) * 100 & ".0%" & sDelim & "-" & vSplit(1) * 100 & ".0%"
            Else
                'Positive numbers
                vSplit = Split(pi.Caption, "-")
                If UBound(vSplit) = 1 Then
                    On Error Resume Next
                    vSplit(0) = vSplit(0) * 100
                    vSplit(1) = vSplit(1) * 100
                    On Error GoTo 0
                ElseIf UBound(vSplit) = 3 Then
                    ' There's some kind of bug with Excel's Grouping feature whereby
                    ' the zero grouping sometimes shows as scientific notation  e.g. -2.77555756156289E-17
                    ' So we'll test for this, and change it to zero
                    If IsNumeric(Join(Array(vSplit(2), vSplit(3)), "-")) Then
                        vSplit(0) = vSplit(1) * -100
                        vSplit(1) = 0
                    End If
                End If
                .Caption = vSplit(0) & ".0%" & sDelim & vSplit(1) & ".0%"
                End If
        End If
    End With
     sCaption = Replace$(sCaption, "to", sDelim)
Next pi

pf.Parent.ManualUpdate = False

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why is the delimeter "--"?

Answer (score 3):

I've also amended the code to make it a generic routine so that you can pass in the number format you want. You can now specify different lower bounds and upper bounds, and can also pass in an optional parameter called dBreakPoint that reduces the upper limit of each grouping.

```
Sub PercentGroupings(pf As PivotField, _
                lFrom As Double, _
                lTo As Double, _
                lGroup As Double, _
                Optional vFormat As Variant, _
                Optional dBreakPoint As Double = 0, _
                Optional sDelim As String = " to ")

    Dim pi          As PivotItem
    Dim sCaption    As String
    Dim vSplit      As Variant
    Dim vItem       As Variant
    Dim i           As Long


    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With


    On Error Resume Next
    pf.LabelRange.Ungroup
    On Error GoTo 0
    pf.LabelRange.Group Start:=lFrom, End:=lTo, By:=lGroup
    pf.Parent.ManualUpdate = True

    If IsMissing(vFormat) Then vFormat = pf.NumberFormat
    If vFormat = "General" Then vFormat = ""


    'Format so that groupings appear as % values
    For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        With pi
            If InStr(.Caption, "<") > 0 Then
                'Less Than Group
                .Caption = "<" & Format(Split(.Caption, "<")(1), vFormat)
            ElseIf InStr(.Caption, ">") > 0 Then
                'Greater Than Group
                .Caption = ">" & Format(Split(.Caption, ">")(1), vFormat)
            Else
                sCaption = ""
                vSplit = Split(pi.Caption, "--")
                If UBound(vSplit) = 1 Then
                    'Negative numbers
                    .Caption = Format(vSplit(0), vFormat) & sDelim & "-" & Format(vSplit(1) - dBreakPoint, vFormat)
                Else
                    'Positive numbers
                    vSplit = Split(pi.Caption, "-")
                    Select Case UBound(vSplit)
                    Case 2
                        'Grouping spans zero
                        vSplit(0) = -vSplit(1)
                        vSplit(1) = vSplit(2)
                    Case 3
                        ' There's some kind of bug with Excel's Grouping feature whereby
                        ' the zero grouping sometimes shows as scientific notation  e.g. -2.77555756156289E-17
                        ' So we'll test for this, and change it to zero
                        If IsNumeric(Join(Array(vSplit(2), vSplit(3)), "-")) Then
                            vSplit(0) = -vSplit(1)
                            vSplit(1) = 0
                        End If
                    End Select
                    .Caption = Format(vSplit(0), vFormat) & sDelim & Format(vSplit(1) - dBreakPoint, vFormat)
                    End If
            End If
        End With
         sCaption = Replace$(sCaption, "to", sDelim)
    Next pi

    pf.Parent.ManualUpdate = False

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
    End Sub
```

You call it like this:

```
Sub FormatPivotGroups()

Dim pf As PivotField

Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Price Difference") '<= Change as appropriate
PercentGroupings pf, -1, 1, 0.1, "0%"
End Sub
```

...which has this result:

[image]

If you want to set the upper range so that it is less than the lower range of the next possible grouping, you use something like this:

```
PercentGroupings pf, -1, 1, 0.1, "0%", 0.001
```

...which has this effect:

[image]

If you wanted to group anything below 0 together, you just need to change that first argument from a -1 to a 0:

```
PercentGroupings pf, 0, 1, 0.1, "0%", 0.001
```

...which has this result:

[image]

And if you wanted to use a dash (or anything else) as a delimiter instead of the default word " to " then you would call it like this:

```
PercentGroupings pf, 0, 1, 0.1, "0%", 0.001, " - "
```

...which would have this effect:

[image]

You can change the format applied too. So if you wanted those figures to show as dollars and in bands that were 99 cents wide, then you would call it like this:

```
PercentGroupings pf, 0, 1, 0.1, "$0.00", 0.01, " - "
```

...which has this result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I think it came close but the issues with the function is that it set ranges based on the last values, 0.1 and if I set it to be 0.099, my second range will start the same value which I do not wish. I was hoping to get each range 9.9% but change the starting value to be 10.0%, 20.0%.

Comment: Okay. I have an idea that might fix this, and make this code more general purpose. I'll see if I can find time to amend the code.

Comment: Thanks I will start a bounty. Thanks

Comment: Like you see in my results, anything below 0.0% is in one group and anything above 100.0% is in one group. And in between ranges are 9.9% but I need to starting values to be 10.0% or 20.0%.